# How to send excel file with nodemailer

Tags: angular, nodemailer, js-xlsx

I'm trying to send an email with an excel file attached, but when I open it an error pops up saying that the file is damaged.
It also downloads the file (which I actually don't want to) and I can open that with no problem.

I'm using the `js-xlsx` library to create the file and the `nodemailer` library to send it.

Function in `email.service.ts`:

```
sendEmail(values: any) {
    let message: {from: string, to: string, subject: string, html: string, attachments: {}[] | null} = {
        from: 'gestionepresenze@gmail.com',
        to: values.email,
        subject: values.oggetto,
        html: this.storage.createTable(values.messaggio).outerHTML,
        attachments: null
    }

    if (values.attach) {
        message["attachments"] = [{
            filename: values.fileName + '.xlsx',
            content: this.excel.createExcel(values),
            contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        }]
    }

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/send', message)
}
```

Function in `excel.service.ts`:

```
createExcel(values: any) {
    const fileName = values.fileName + '.xlsx';
    const table = this.storage.createTable('');
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Presenze');
    return XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

First of all the right method is `XLSX.write(wb, {type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx'});`, not `XLSX.writeFile(...)`.

But the server was still throwing an error, saying that I was passing an `Object`. The problem was that I was sending what I *thought* was an `Uint8Array`, while the node app was *actually* receiving an `Object`.

Why? I don't know.

But knowing this I now convert the content to a `Uint8Array` directly in the node app.

Here's how I changed the code:

Function in `email.service.ts`:

```
sendEmail(values: any) {
    let message: {from: string, to: string, subject: string, html: string, attachments: {}[] | null} = {
        from: 'gestionepresenze@gmail.com',
        to: values.email,
        subject: values.oggetto,
        html: this.storage.createTable(values.messaggio).outerHTML,
        attachments: null
    }

    if (values.attach) {
        message["attachments"] = [{
            filename: values.fileName + '.xlsx',
            content: this.excel.createExcel(values)
        }]
    }

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/send', message)
}
```

Function in `excel.service.ts`:

```
createExcel(values: any) {
    const fileName = values.fileName + '.xlsx';
    const table = this.storage.createTable('');
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Presenze');
    return XLSX.write(wb, {type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx'});
}
```

Function in the node app to send the email:

```
fastify.post('/send', (request, reply) => {
    let content = request.body.attachments[0].content;
    let array = new Uint8Array(Object.entries(content).length);

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(content)) {
        array[key] = value;
    }

    request.body.attachments[0].content = array;
    const mailOptions = request.body
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for you. Can you maybe take a screenshot of the request body from the network tab of your browser? I am interested in seeing what is actually contained in the request body.

Comment: @fabian there's some Italian in there, I hope it's not a problem: https://imgur.com/AmLPWTJ. What I think is happening is that the function creates a javascript object with the properties of an Uint8Array.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/write-options) I can see the following:

> XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename, write_opts) attempts to write wb to filename. In browser-based environments, it will attempt to force a client-side download.

This is the reason a download is triggered on your client.

You probably want to use `XLSX.write(workbook, { type: "array", bookType: "xlsx" });`, so that an `Uint8Array` is returned from the function and attached as content to your form data.

Comment: what should the content type be at that point?

Comment: Well, content type is an optional property, so I would suggest to just don't set it (if not set will be derived from the filename property).

Comment: Didn't word unfortunately. The server throws this error: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object"

Comment: This is strange, since setting 'array' as return type should return an Uint8Array. Nevertheless you can also try to set type to "buffer".

Comment: Same result. I even tried other return types and other methods. Most of the times it throws the same error and if it doesn't, the file results damaged.

Comment: I have an update: I used "XLSX.write(wb, {type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx'})" and logged the result to the console and it says it's a Uint8Array, but when I pass it to nodemailer it says it's an Object (as you can see in the error)

Comment: okay it works now, here's how and why https://stackoverflow.com/a/74030751/20212996. Thanks for the help, I didn't think about types before your answer.